# ionic build android fails with namespace error

Tags: cordova, google-maps, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 framework on a map based application. I followed the steps to include typings for google.maps and faced no issues with ionic serve and testing on the browser. But while doing a build for android platform, i run into the below issues.

```
[08:16:22] ionic-app-scripts 0.0.38
[08:16:23] build prod started ...
[08:16:23] clean started ...
[08:16:23] clean finished in 5 ms
[08:16:23] copy started ...
[08:16:23] ngc started ...
[08:16:24] lint started ...
[08:16:25] copy finished in 2.21 s
[08:16:56] lint finished in 32.03 s
[08:17:29] Error: Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/components/map/map.ts:10:15
[08:17:29] Cannot find namespace 'google'.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/components/map/map.ts:22:27
[08:17:29] Cannot find name 'google'.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/components/map/map.ts:27:18
[08:17:29] Cannot find name 'google'.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/components/map/map.ts:32:19
[08:17:29] Cannot find name 'google'.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/components/map/map.ts:37:26
[08:17:29] Cannot find name 'google'.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/components/map/map.ts:40:24
[08:17:29] Cannot find name 'google'.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/components/map/map.ts:42:21
[08:17:29] Cannot find name 'google'.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/components/map/map.ts:44:26
[08:17:29] Cannot find name 'google'.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/pages/list-page/list-page.ngfactory.ts:642:72
[08:17:29] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/pages/list-page/list-page.ngfactory.ts:648:72
[08:17:29] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/pages/list-page/list-page.ngfactory.ts:846:72
[08:17:29] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/pages/list-page/list-page.ngfactory.ts:852:72
[08:17:29] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/pages/detail-page/detail-page.ngfactory.ts:708:73
[08:17:29] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
[08:17:29] Error at G:/Projects/.tmp/pages/detail-page/detail-page.ngfactory.ts:719:73
[08:17:29] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
[08:17:29] ngc failed
[08:17:29] ionic-app-script task: "build"
[08:17:29] Error: Error
```

Below is a code snipped of my map.ts typescript file

```
public map: google.maps.Map;
....
var dflt_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.132633, 5.291266);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

the google namespace is not being recognised while building the platform. I am not sure if there is any configuration file that needs to be updated. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: did you add `declare var google: any;` under your `import`s and above your `@Component` ?

Comment: no. could you share a sample snippet how it looks?

Comment: `//all imports here
import { .. } from '...'; declare var google: any; @Component({}) export class App{} `